# Anylogic multiple agents in same block

Tags: java, simulation, anylogic

How to set agent type dynamically in agent type of advanced section in service block. For example let's say
we have two type customers and both are served by same service block. In want to change the agent type based on type of customer, how to do this in anylogic?

The two customer are regular customers(reg_cust) and card holder customers(ch_cust);
Initially I have set the color for these two agents in their respective source blocks  using agent.setColor() , red for regular and orange for cardholder. Now in service block , in advanced section in the agent type I used the following code:

if (agent.getColor() == red) {
return reg_cust;}

else if (agent.getColor() == orange) {
return ch_cust;

The reason I set different colors is that I couldn't differentiate between agents when they pass through same block. I cant call the parameters that I set for these two agents.

Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

It is not 100% clear what you mean, but maybe this helps:

if you want to different agent types to flow through a block, but still access their individual characteristics, set the block's expected agent type to `Agent` (the most general option).

In the code fields of the block, you can distinguish and access fields like:

```
if (agent instanceof AgentType1) {
    ((AgentType1)agent).getSomeFieldOrMethodFromType1();
} else {
    ((AgentType2)agent).getSomeFieldOrMethodFromType2();
}
```

Comment: Thankyou that helped and the issue is sorted out , could you please clarify 
this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76097984/anylogic-hold-block )